# How to reduce cost of sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using SQL COUNT query, but query cost  much higher. Indexes added in Table but no effect on query cost.
Query :

```
SELECT COUNT(direction) AS directionCount,  direction, destination_addr, record_timestamp
FROM traffic_direction WHERE destination_addr='10.255.2.11' 
 GROUP BY  destination_addr, direction ORDER BY record_timestamp DESC limit 10
```

Use Explain to get query cost which is:

```
  "cost_info": {
  "query_cost": "14158682.20"
    }
```

Comment: ORDER BY generally requires extra computation resources. And the LIMIT clause will not decrease the computation cost of the query. Do you really need to have the query ordered?

Comment: yes i need that .

Comment: can you show us the explain plan?

Comment: "table":{"table_name":"traffic_direction","access_type":"ALL","possible_keys":["detination_addr_full_text"],"rows_examined_per_scan":69163011,"rows_produced_per_join":1,"filtered":"0.00","cost_info":{"read_cost":"14158681.80","eval_cost":"0.40","prefix_cost":"14158682.20","data_read_per_join":"1K"},"used_columns":["id","record_timestamp","`detination_addr`","direction"],"attached_condition":"((`acldb`.`traffic_direction`.`detination_addr` = '10.255.2.11') or (`acldb`.`traffic_direction`.`detination_addr` = '10.255.2.11'))"}

Answer (score 1):

First, your query is malformed and should be returning a syntax error.  Why?  The `SELECT` is inconsistent with the `GROUP BY` -- because `record_timestamp` is not aggregated.  So, write the query as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS directionCount, direction, 
       destination_addr, MAX(record_timestamp)
FROM traffic_direction
WHERE destination_addr = '10.255.2.11' 
GROUP BY destination_addr, direction
ORDER BY record_timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

This won't affect the performance, though.

About the only thing you can do is create an index on `traffic_direction(destination_addr, direction, record_timestamp)`.

MySQL probably will not use this for the `GROUP BY` -- and you will still incur the overhead of the sort for the `ORDER BY`.  But it will help filtering the data and eliminate the need to access the data pages.